# Is there a way to send client credentials in request body for the token call in Next-Auth?

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, next.js, openid-connect, next-auth

I am implementing authentication using Next-Auth and the authentication server I am using is based on openid connect. Initially, I have tested it in the Postman's Authorization Tab with `client-id`, `client-secret`, `redirect-url`, `scope`, `grant-type=authorization_code`, etc. and "Client Authentication" set to `"Send client credentials in body"`. The call happens successfully and I receive all the tokens.

[image]

However, when I set the Client Authentication method as `Send as Basic Auth Header` the token call fails because the authentication server's token endpoint is expecting the `client-secret` to be included in the token request body.

Now in Next-Auth the call is failing because of the same reason. I am using a custom provider and have tried getting authenticated through google which worked fine. I have looked up next-auth documentation but wasn't able to find anything on configuring token authentication method. Is there a way to send client credentials in request body for the token call in Next-Auth?

Comment: You should send the server's clientId and clientSecret to the token endpoint. Not the credentials of the user who sent you the token.

Comment: By client credentials what it means is `client_id` and `client_secret`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved by changing the authentication server settings; client authentication method was changed to HTTP Basic. Still I wonder why Next-Auth doesn't have client authentication method configurable in their custom provider configurations.